# VBA Selection.Find returns offset cell

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I am having problems with my code. I am trying to inset values into a "database" by using the find function to identify the correct rownumber. when i run the code the find function returns the next rownumber ie. the serchname is in row 300 but the data is inserted in row 301.

the code i am using is as follows:

```
For Each Cell In Workbooks(controlfile).Sheets("Lab").Range("B9:B56")
    If Cell.Value <> "" Then
        
'Range("N" & latestRow).Value = Right(DataArray(1), 4) & Right(DataArray(2), 4)
'Range("N" & latestRow).NumberFormat = "00000000"
        
        
        
        
        søgeOrd = Right(Cell.Value, 4) & Right(Cell.Offset(0, 1), 4)
        Workbooks(controlfile).Sheets("Lab").Range("A1").Value = søgeOrd
        Workbooks(controlfile).Sheets("Lab").Range("A1").NumberFormat = "00000000"
        LinjeL = Cell.Row
        FGM = Workbooks(controlfile).Sheets("Lab").Range("F" & LinjeL).Value
        STA = Workbooks(controlfile).Sheets("Lab").Range("I" & LinjeL).Value
        BMK = Workbooks(controlfile).Sheets("Lab").Range("J" & LinjeL).Value
        VK = Workbooks(controlfile).Sheets("Lab").Range("L" & LinjeL).Value
        DP = Workbooks(controlfile).Sheets("Lab").Range("M" & LinjeL).Value
        SNB = Workbooks(controlfile).Sheets("Lab").Range("N" & LinjeL).Value
        Workbooks(controlfile).Sheets("Lab").Range("A1").ClearContents
        
        
        
        
        'find søgeord i database og indsæt de værdier som er fundet i lab
       
        Workbooks(FileName).Sheets("Database").Activate
        Columns("N:N").Select
        Set cellD = Selection.Find(What:=Workbooks(controlfile).Sheets("Lab").Range("A1").Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
        If Not cellD Is Nothing Then LinjeD = cellD.Row
               
       
        If Range("E" & LinjeD).Value <> "" Then
        
        'kopier alle data til fejllog hvis der allerede er data
        Range("A" & LinjeD).Select
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
        Workbooks(FileName).Worksheets("Fejllog").Activate
        LastLine = Workbooks(FileName).Sheets("Fejllog").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Range("A" & LastLine).PasteSpecial
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        
        Workbooks(FileName).Sheets("Database").Activate
        
        Range("E" & LinjeD).Value = FGM
        Range("H" & LinjeD).Value = STA
        Range("I" & LinjeD).Value = BMK
        Range("O" & LinjeD).Value = Format(Now, "dd.mm.yyyy")
        Range("P" & LinjeD).Value = VK
        Range("Q" & LinjeD).Value = DP
        Range("R" & LinjeD).Value = SNB
        
        Workbooks(controlfile).Sheets("Lab").Activate
        
        Else
        
        Range("E" & LinjeD).Value = FGM
        Range("H" & LinjeD).Value = STA
        Range("I" & LinjeD).Value = BMK
        Range("O" & LinjeD).Value = Format(Now, "dd.mm.yyyy")
        Range("P" & LinjeD).Value = VK
        Range("Q" & LinjeD).Value = DP
        Range("R" & LinjeD).Value = SNB
        
         Workbooks(controlfile).Sheets("Lab").Activate

        End If
        
    End If
Next Cell
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You did not show us **exactly the problematic part**: How does our code insert something? It is nothing wrong with the code you presented, since it founds the cell. To be sure that my supposition is correct, try inserting the next line `Debug.Print LinjeD` immediately after the line where it is defined (last one of your above code). What does it return in Immediate Window? I am sure that it returns what is should.

Comment: My code inserts values from variables in empty fields on the row that is found. As i tried to explain above in this example it has to find a unique value in column N:N and return the row number. When i look in the sheet the value is in row 300, but my code returns row 301. I don't know if it is relevant but it is code that looks into another workbook. i will try to update the code above, so it includes a larger portion.

Comment: I'm missing the line, like, `Debug.Print cellID.Value` and/or `Debug.Print cellID.Address` together with your statement that the print doesn't match reality in some way (which way?)

Answer (score 0):

I re-wrote your code to eliminate use of the `Selection` object.

```
Private Sub Snippet()

    Dim WsDb        As Worksheet
    Dim ClmN        As Range
    Dim cellID      As Range
    Dim What        As Variant
    Dim LineID      As Long
    
    What = Workbooks(controlfile).Sheets("Lab").Range("A1").Value
    Set WsDb = Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Database")
    Set ClmN = WsDb.Columns("N:N")
    Set cellD = ClmN.Find(What:=What, After:=ActiveCell, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                          MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
    If Not cellD Is Nothing Then LinjeD = cellD.Row
End Sub
```

Observe how the definition of the worksheet on which you do your search is now done by declaring a variable for it. The code will now work smoothly in the background without screen flickering.

Now you can blame me for destroying your reference to the `ActiveCell`. Did I really? Which cell was active in your code when the *Database* tab was activated? Could have been anyone or none. Now the code will crash because the `ActiveCell` isn't in the `ClmN` range. Obviously, you need to specify a cell in that range for starting the search.

Does the `cellID` range start in a row other than where `What` was found? I doubt it and you don't claim so, either. You say that a row gets inserted at a point other than LineID. That is normal and has to do with the action of inserting a row, not related to the code you published. Logically, the new row should take the place of the one you specified. Therefore the cellId.Row would now be one row lower than before. However, I got this wrong many times. Therefore I always test which row is the old and which one the new. It's not difficult - and it's always the same.

Comment: Thank you for the cleanup. it looks alot better than before :)

Comment: However i am not inserting a new row, just finding the row number and adding data to some of the empty columns in the row.

Comment: Are you saying the `LineID` returned by the above function isn't in the row where `What` was found?

Comment: @Colin Shields: I think that this only mean that what you see in the cell where you expect the code to find the cell, is not exactly what it should... I mean, check please if an extra space exists in the string in discussion. I also suppose that the next row contains also the same `What` and the method skips the one above not matching it. Is this supposition correct?

Comment: No, the cell row that is returned is empty. The value is unique as it is a unique identifier for the specific line.

Comment: Try to loop to `cellID` cell instead of using `Find`. Basically, shift your focus from finding a fault in your code to finding a fault with your testing. Since the `Find` function can't be at fault the fault must be elsewhere. Testing is first in line, followed by a corrupted workbook, a faulty installation of Excel, of Windows, virus action. You name it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

I had mistakenly cleared the content of the cell used as the search name before the search began. this resulted in a search for an empty cell.

Thank you to all of you for making inputs, and helping me clean up my code :)

It is amazing how you can spend hours looking at something, only to find the answer is right in front of you.

Comment: As I said, if the program isn't at fault it must be the test. This isn't entirely heard of elsewhere :-)